# Why Node.js does not wait for promise to resolve before exiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When I execute the following code, I thought Node.js will wait till we call the `resolve`. Till then the `myPromise` will be in the `<pending>` state. Then how come node exits before it resolves?

The following code exits immediately!

```js
const myPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  // nothing doing with the resolve
});

myPromise
  .then(() => console.log('result'))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

---

**Update 1:** I renamed JavaScript to Node.js to avoid confusion.

Comment: You didn't `await` myPromise.

Comment: Do you want your machine to hang itself until a promise that you forgot to resolve become resolved?

Comment: Are you interested in how they can know this? If no task is pending anywhere, and no event is being listened to, your Promise won't ever be resolved.

Comment: Basically, like @Kaiido says: Node exists _when there are no pending tasks_. `resolve => {}` in your example is a function that doesn't start any new tasks. If there were a `setTimeout` or `fetch`, there would be a pending task. If you were to call `resolve()` there would be one, too. But since there are no tasks to run, it's' free to exit.

Comment: @Unmitigated node doesn't kill the process as soon as the original script is executed, that would be pretty bad.

Comment: JavaScript will run `console.log('result')` once `resolve()` is called from inside of `new Promise(resolve => {})`. Learn more about [Promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: See [How the Event Loop Works in Node.js](https://heynode.com/tutorial/how-event-loop-works-nodejs/). In particular: "A Node.js process exits when there is no more pending work in the Event Loop, or when process.exit() is called manually. A program only runs for as long as there are tasks queued in the Event Loop, or present on the call stack."

Comment: Minor side note: It's entirely possible for a promise to be *resolved* without being *settled* (fulfilled or rejected), or indeed without it *ever* being settled. More in my post on promise terminology [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The following code exits immediately!

What keeps a Node.js process running is *active in-progress work* or the potential for it (pending timers, open sockets that may receive messages, etc.). So for instance, if your code had used `readFile` from `fs/promises` and the promise you were using came from that, Node.js wouldn't just terminate at the end of the code you've shown, because there's an operation in progress (reading the file). From the [The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and `process.nextTick(`) guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick):

> Between each run of the event loop, Node.js checks if it is waiting for any asynchronous I/O or timers and shuts down cleanly if there are not any.

But in your example, there's nothing in progress, Node.js isn't waiting for anything, so it exits.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, NodeJS does use some referencing counting, eg. if you use a `setTimeout`, or `setInterval`, internally there will be some referencing counting.  You can even control this to some extent, in nodeJS you can even call `unref()` on a the return value of `setTimeout / setInterval` to stop them from preventing node closing.

If you wanted to keep node open, no matter what the trick is then to have something were the reference count is greater than 0.  One idea is using a `MessageChannel` from `worker_threads`.

eg.

```
const { MessageChannel } = require('worker_threads');
const port = new MessageChannel();
port.port1.ref();

//nodeJs will now stay open..
//and when your ready to close Node,  `port.port1.unref()
```

Answer (score 1):

Promises are non-blocking. This means that when you invoke the asynchronous function, JavaScript **does not** wait for the promise to resolve. This is the whole purpose of promises: you can allow tasks to execute "in the background" (kind of) while JavaScript executes the rest of the script/function.

The side effect: If the browser/node runtime reaches the end of the script, the program will terminate, regardless of whether the `Promise` is resolved or not.

If you want to block JavaScript from terminating, you will have to **block** the main thread. Here is a solution I just came up with (if anybody has a better solution, leave it in the comments):

```js
async function nonBlocking() { ... }

const interval = 100; // Blocks the main thread in 100 millisecond interval
const blockingInterval = setInterval(() => undefined, 100)

nonBlocking().then(value => {
    clearInterval(blockingInterval)
    // ... Rest of code here
}).catch(err => {
    clearInterval(blockingInterval)
    // ... Handle error here
})
```

Comment: `you will have to block the main thread`  Your terminology here is not really correct.  But your code will keep Node alive because you are keeping an interval alive.

Comment: You're right. I meant to imply that the `interval` without any asynchronous code would technically be "blocking", which prevents the runtime for exiting

Answer (score 1):

Another slant on this is that if the promise executor function, inlined as

```
resolve => {
  // nothing doing with the resolve
}
```

doesn't record the value of `resolve` for later use, or create callbacks in the executor function that call the executor's `resolve` argument, then the executor function can't reach `resolve` in any of its content.

However, `resolve` and `reject` *functions* hold the promise they were issued for in memory since they themselves have internal access to the promise. If `resolve` and/or `reject` are not reachable in code, neither has been called, any externally stored reference(s) to the promise are not reachable either, and the promise has not been used to resolve another promise, the promise becomes eligible for memory garbage collection.

The posted code contains no code referencing `resolve`, and the external reference to the promise, `myPromise`, becomes unreachable after the second statement using it has been executed.

When `myPromise` is gargage collected, its references to resolve and reject functions of the next promise in the chain (the one returned from `then`) are released and so the next promise can be garbage collected, which in turn will release resolve/reject refererences to the one returned from `catch`.

At this point all program data has or can be garbage collected, and in short **the program has run to completion**.